# Compare files content with similar names on two folders

Tags: linux, shell, grep, diff

I have two folders (I'll use database names as example):

- MongoFolder/
- CassandraFolder/

These  two folders have similar files inside like:

- MongoFolder/

  - MongoFile
  - MongoStatus
  - MongoConfiguration
  - MongoPlugin
- CassandraFolder/

  - CassandraFile
  - CassandraStatus
  - CassandraConfiguration

Those files have content also very similar, only changing the name of the database for example, so they all have code or configuration only changing the name `Mongo` for `Cassandra`.

How can I compare this two folders, so the result is the files missing from one to the other (for example the file **CassandraPlugin** for the **CassandraFolder**) and also that the contents of the files alike, have to be similar, only changing the database name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the names of the missing files (minus the database name):

```
find MongoFolder/ CassandraFolder/ | \
      sed -e s/Mongo//g -e s/Cassandra//g | sort | uniq -u
```

*Output:*

```
Folder/Plugin
```

Comment: Will they always be the ones missing from the second folder?

Comment: no just non-pairing folders, I don't have time to improve now

Answer (score 1):

the following provides a full diff, including missing files and changed content:

```
cp -r CassandraFolder cmpFolder
# rename files
find cmpFolder -name "Cassandra*" -print | while read file; do
    mongoName=`echo "$file" | sed 's/Cassandra/Mongo/'`
    mv "$file" "$mongoName"
done
# fix content
find cmpFolder -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/Cassandra/Mongo/g' {} \;

# inspect result
diff -r MongoFolder cmpFolder # or use a gui tool like kdiff3
```

I haven't tested this though, feel free fix bugs or to ask if something specific is unclear.
Instead of `mv` you can also use `rename` but that's different on different flavours of linux.